# How to change image in subviews (UIImageView) in runtime?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a uiStackView with 5 UIImageViews, I need to change the image in this imageView in runtime.

Now I remove all subviews, generate new UIImageViews, and add it like subviews, but its bad practice for performance. I try It:

```
let targetStar = Int(floorf(value * Float(uiStars.subviews.count))) - 1
let factor = CGFloat(min(1, max(self.value, 0)))
let starsCount = uiStars.subviews.count
uiStars.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

for i in 0..<starsCount {
    if i < targetStar {
        let starView = UIImageView(image: star!.maskWithColor(color: UIColor.blue.cgColor, factor: 0))
        starView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        uiStars.addArrangedSubview(starView)
    }
    else if i == targetStar {
        let starView = UIImageView(image: star!.maskWithColor(color: UIColor.blue.cgColor, factor: factor))
        starView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        uiStars.addArrangedSubview(starView)
    }
    else {
        let starView = UIImageView(image: star!)
        starView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        uiStars.addArrangedSubview(starView)
    }
}
```

I expect something like that

```
for i in 0..<starsCount {
    if i < targetStar {
        let view = uiStars.subviews[i]
        view.image = star!.maskWithColor(color: UIColor.blue.cgColor, factor: 0)
    }
    else if i == targetStar {
        let view = uiStars.subviews[i]
        view.image = star!.maskWithColor(color: UIColor.blue.cgColor, factor: factor)
    } 
    else {
        let view = uiStars.subviews[i]
        view.image = star!
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
let targetStar = Int(floorf(value * Float(uiStars.subviews.count))) - 1
let factor = CGFloat(min(1, max(self.value, 0)))
let starsCount = uiStars.subviews.count

for i in 0..<starsCount {
    if i < targetStar {
      let view = uiStars.subviews[i] as! UIImageView
      view.image = star!.maskWithColor(color: UIColor.blue.cgColor, factor: 0)
    } else if i == targetStar {
        let view = uiStars.subviews[i] as! UIImageView
        view.image = star!.maskWithColor(color: UIColor.blue.cgColor, factor: factor)
    } else {
        let view = uiStars.subviews[i] as! UIImageView
        view.image = star!
    }
}
```